# How to Create an Amazon S3 Access Policy to Restrict User Access to Their Own Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with the following folder structure:

`/users/<userId>/*`

There is only one folder inside the root level of the bucket, named "users." Inside the "users" folder, there are multiple subfolders, and each subfolder is named after a userId. Each user should only be able to access their own userId folder.

I need to create an S3 access policy where a given user, let's say with a userId of "123," can only access their own folder inside the "users" folder with permissions to perform GetObject, PutObject, and DeleteObject operations within that folder.

Additionally, this user should not have access to view or access other users' folders or even see their names inside the "users" folder. However, they should be able to perform a GetObject operation on the root level of the bucket ("/") and see the "users" folder.

I need a S3 bucket policy that accomplishes these access restrictions?

Note: Each user will be assined a IAM role and this S3 policy will be assigned to that IAM role.

I tried multiple s3 policies where I was able to achieve the restriction to only the userId folder but was not able to give the getObject access also at the root level without preventing the access to users folder.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::userbucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "users/123/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::userbucket/users/123/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to use the context from the request to limit access to your prefix in S3, more information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html).
For your question about limit the user try using the username in the resource
and for limiting the user to the bucket root I would use the "ListBucket" permission, so your policy could look something like this

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/users/${aws:username}/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for the use case. with this policy, I am able to access the "users" folder along with the root level.